# Why was Nixon’s face never shown in the "The Post" movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-post

We could only see Nixon's back but not his face.

[image]

why was Nixon’s face never shown in the movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It wasn't necessary.

The conversations you are hearing are [**actual recordings**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixon_White_House_tapes) from the listening devices which were installed in the White House by/for Nixon.

Using an actor to play Nixon to speak those words would have been redundant. It's much **more impactful and dramatic** to use the real person's *actual* voice and film it as though we are just seeing the Oval Office from outside.